# Running sklearn classifier on sparse dataframe

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I have a pandas dataframe with a list of features, one of which is a string. I am trying to use any sklearn classifier on it. I know in sklearn, not even DecisionTrees implemetation allows for strings, so I using One Hot Encoding.
I created a function, where df is the dataframe and feature is the categorical feature:

```
def OneHotEncoding(df, cat_feature):

    dv = DictVectorizer()
    dictionary = pandas.DataFrame(series[cat_feature]).to_dict(orient='records') 
    X = dv.fit_transform(dictionary) 
    columns = []
    for i in range(X.shape[1]):
        columns.append(str(i))

    series = series.reset_index()

    Y = pandas.SparseDataFrame(X, columns=columns)
    new_df= pandas.DataFrame.join(df, Y, how='outer')

    return new_df
```

Then I use new_df to pass it to my classifier:

```
alg = LogisticRegression(random_state=1)) 
alg.fit(new_df, labels)
```

but in my .fit function I get the error:

```
  File "xxx.py", line 442
    alg.fit(X, train_labels_input)

  File "C:\Applications\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 739, in fit
    X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)

  File "C:\Applications\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 122, in fit
    X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")

  File "C:\Applications\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 407, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array)

  File "C:\Applications\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 58, in _assert_all_finite
    " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

If I do not use a SparseDataFrame and I do:

```
Y = pandas.DataFrame(X.todense(), columns=columns)
```

it works.

How can I use SparseDataFrame to avoid memory errors?

Comment: Its not clear. Where does this error come, which classifier? Can you post the complete code and stack trace

Comment: Hi @VivekKumar, there is not much code. OneHotEncoding returns a new df that includes one hot encoding for the one categorical feature. I pass that to a fit function (in this case Linear Regression). I attached the whole stack. The problem is that the the sparse data frame has many NaN, but if I remove them, then it is not sparse anymore, and I have memory issues.

Answer (score 2):

The LogisticRegression in Sklean accepts sparse matrices (as many others Sklearn algorithms). You can check the *fit* attributes in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit)
Try converting your SparseDataFrame to a sparse matrix with SparseDataFrame.to_coo() method, before calling the *fit*.